# mbedtls entropy generation (nv_seed)

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, embedded, freertos, mbedtls

I am using mbedtls as TLS library for amazon FreeRTOS running on my hardware(SAM4E).

The library has been ported and I am using **nv_seed** method to generate random numbers. I am reading and writing the 32Bit data to EEPROM.

I was getting the TLS handshake failure(hang). After debugging, I found out that the numbers saved and read from EEPROM is same all the time and that is the reason for handshake failure.

I cannot generate random numbers using hardware as I do not have dedicated TRNG. So, I have to make the seeding work somehow.

Comment: Have you enabled `MBEDTLS_ENTROPY_NV_SEED` and implemented the read \ write functions setting them in `mbedtls_platform_set_nv_seed` if you defined `MBEDTLS_PLATFORM_NV_SEED_ALT` or define these read \ write functions as `MBEDTLS_PLATFORM_NV_SEED_READ_MACRO` and `MBEDTLS_PLATFORM_NV_SEED_WRITE_MACRO` respectively?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have done everything you said. But, it does not matter now as I changed the hardware I was working on because of the absence of TRNG. Thanks anyway!

Comment: couds it be priviliges issue on EEPROM? Do you have the right permissions to write and read to \ from EEPROM?